# AIR 4.0 flash.desktop::NativeApplication is not defined

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have done this many time before but can't seem to fix this. I simply want to exit an AIR Desktop application running on Windows 8 with touch. So I have the following code:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;

btn_exit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, exit);

function exit(e:TouchEvent) {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
        }
```

Even though it compiles, when I touch the exit button I get variable not found error:

```
Error #1065: Variable flash.desktop::NativeApplication is not defined
```

Any ideas how to fix this please?

Comment: I checked `NativeApplication` and your code in an Air Desktop Project and I changed `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` to `"click"` (because I have no touch screen for windows). That worked without any error.

Comment: I created a new swf with just the code above, and it worked as expected. I then added my existing classes to this file, then tested again, and got the same error as previous `Variable flash.desktop::NativeApplication is not defined`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

i am using `close()`, it works on win 7.

Comment: Thanks Anas, but it is not an issue with functionality, it is a case of not being able to use the NativeApplication class. The same issue arises if I use NativeWindow.close() even after importing the NativeWindow class specifically.

Comment: Can you post your complete project i believe there is error in some place.